# perl + shell script + remove all not uniq lines except the first line uniq (FILE NAME) + perl in shell script

Tags: perl

I have the following file, how to remove by `sed` all `FILE NAME` lines except the first unique `FILE NAME` For example need to remove all `FILE NAME` lines from the file except the first:

```
FILE NAME: /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/file

FILE NAME: /dirA/dirB/dirC/dirD/dirE/file
```

the file:

> FILE NAME: /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/file
>
> PARAMETER NAME: blablabla
>
> TARGET FILE: 12
>
> SOURCE FILE: 565
>
> FILE NAME: /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/file
>
> PARAMETER NAME: blablabla
>
> TARGET FILE: 18
>
> SOURCE FILE: 552
>
> FILE NAME: /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/file
>
> PARAMETER NAME: blablabla
>
> TARGET FILE: 14
>
> SOURCE FILE: 559
>
> FILE NAME: /dirA/dirB/dirC/dirD/dirE/file
>
> PARAMETER NAME: blablabla
>
> TARGET FILE: 134
>
> SOURCE FILE: 344
>
> FILE NAME: /dirA/dirB/dirC/dirD/dirE/file
>
> PARAMETER NAME: blablabla
>
> TARGET FILE: 13
>
> SOURCE FILE: 445
>
> FILE NAME: /dirA/dirB/dirC/dirD/dirE/file
>
> PARAMETER NAME: blablabla
>
> TARGET FILE: 13

Comment: programming related questions should not be on superuser. Please ask on stackoverflow.com

Comment: @gruntled: please don't tell people to ask on Stack Overflow or Server Fault.  questions will be migrated there if necessary.  if you tell them to ask on those sites they tend to crosspost, which means this question, when migrated, will be a duplicate.  also, some scripting questions are acceptable here.

Comment: this appears to be a rehash of http://superuser.com/questions/152737/awk-remove-all-not-uniq-lines-except-the-first-line-uniq-file-name using *sed* or *perl* instead of *awk* ...

Comment: point taken. Thanks for the lesson in etiquette :)

Comment: Sorry, still not clear what you want to do.  Can you add more info to the question, and format the data above so we can tell what is in file and what is part of the question?  The way I look at it, using awk or perl it would be simple.  So I have to ask, is sed a requirement?

Answer (score 0):

```
$line_count = 0;
open (OLD_FILE, "<$old_file") or die ("Could not open $old_file.");
open (NEW_FILE, ">$new_file") or die ("Could not open $new_file.");
while (<OLD_FILE>) {
    chomp ($_);
    if ($_ =~ /^FILE NAME/) {
        $line_count++;
        if ($line_count > 1) {
            next;
        }
    }
    print NEW_FILE "$_\n";
)
close (FILE);
```

This does a pattern match on each line of our old file. If the line begins with "FILE NAME" and we have already matched this once, then it does not print anymore of these lines to our new file.